# how can I delete image outside its path

Tags: php

I have a folder called holder. Inside holder I also have two directories named pics and script.

Inside script directory I have a script for deleting images inside pics folder.

I may want to delete images inside pics.

Note that my script(file) to achieve this is inside the script folder for some reasons.

```
<?php

$dir="pics/";

$imgid=$id.".jpg";

unlink($dir.$imgid);

?>
```

Comment: are you using real path in unlink() .

Comment: what is your problem or issue you face

Comment: give complete path of the file to delete it.

Comment: How to write the path correctly. script above is looking for the folder photos inside itself

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what do you need from your question but I guess your issue is that you are in the wrong directory. If you have the script inside `script` directory (**and you call it from that place!**) then you have two options to solve that, switch working directory or just correct your path.

1) Switch working directory

```
chdir("..");
$dir="pics/";
$imgid=$id.".jpg";
unlink($idir.$imgid);
```

2) Correct the path to delete

```
$dir="../pics/";
$imgid=$id.".jpg";
unlink($idir.$imgid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$dir= dirname(__FILE__) . "/../pics/";
$imgid=$id.".jpg";

if( file_exists( $dir.$imgid ) ) {
   unlink($dir.$imgid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<?php
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . "../pics/";
    $imgid = $id . ".jpg";
    unlink($path . $imgid);
?>
```

Comment: I think it's not relative cuz he said that the script is inside `script` directory. But still a good idea to use `__FILE__`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $dir="pics/";

    $imgid=$id.".jpg";

    unlink(dirname(__FILE__).$dir.$imgid);

?>
```